# Define additional relationship on many-to-many polymorphic relationship

Tags: laravel

I'm creating an taggable table like so:

```php
Schema::create('taggable', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();

    $table->unsignedBigInteger('tag_id');
    $table->foreign('tag_id')->references('id')->on('tags')->onDelete('cascade');

    $table->unsignedBigInteger('taggable_id');
    
    $table->string('taggable_type');

    $table->unsignedBigInteger('company_id');
    $table->foreign('company_id')->references('id')->on('companies')->onDelete('cascade');

    $table->unsignedBigInteger('created_by')->nullable();
    $table->foreign('created_by')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('set null');

    $table->timestamps();
});
```

As you can see, next to connecting `tags` to a `Post`, `Video` etc (as per the Laravel docs example), I'd also like to ensure that the row that's added is connected to a `Company` and `User` model so I can keep track who it belongs to and who created it, but even more so access properties from those models in controllers and views.

I know that in my `Post` model I can do:

```php
public function tags()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany(\App\Models\Tag::class, 'taggable')->withPivot('created_by', 'company_id', 'created_at');
}
```

The problem is that this will retrieve just the value for `created_by` and `company_id` and not the Eloquent model. Is this possible?

So what I'd like to do is access properties of those relationships in controllers and views like so:

```php
$post = Post::findOrFail(1);

foreach($post->tags as $tag) {
  $tag->created_by->name // accessing 'name' property on the `User` model
}

foreach($post->tags as $tag) {
  $tag->company->address // accessing `address` property on the `Company` model
}
```

Comment: each post has many tags so this query you want is wrong.

Comment: You're right, I wrote the last bit wrong, thanks! I updated it now. See the `foreach` loop, that's what I want to achieve so the question is still the same.

Answer (score 1):

You must do like below:

first you must define relationship between tags and users

```
class Tags extends Model
{
    public function taggable(): MorphTo
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    public function createdBy(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'created_by');
    }
}
```

then for achieve that you want you must:

```
$post = Post::first();
$users = $post->tags()->with('createdBy')->get();
```

Comment: You should do the same for the company

Comment: If I do that then it's a *one-to-one* or a *one-to-many* polymorphic relationship, but not a *many-to-many* polymorphic relationship like I need it to be.

Comment: the many to many polymorphic relationship is between tag and post. to achieve that the morphTo keyword was added. for your other relation that is between tags and users you must define different relationship. for your case this doesn't sounds polymorphic relation.

Comment: It's polymorphic because I also want to be able to connect `tags` to more models than just `Post`. This is literally the many-to-many polymorphic example from the Laravel docs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations

Comment: some misundrasanding: the relation between tag and post-video is polymorphic. but the relation between tags and user-company is not polymorphic. that's all.